# How to create an ActionLink that retains the parameters from the request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view responding to the action `/Page/Index/{id}` (default ASP.NET MVC routing). The view contains action links that lead to the same action with the same `id` but with an added parameter in the URL. I've put something like this in place:

```
@Html.ActionLink("SetVar1", "Index", new { var1 = "true" } )
@Html.ActionLink("SetVar2", "Index", new { var2 = "true" } )
```

As expected, clicking on one of those links redirects me to the same action with the same `id` and with a parameter.

```
Page/Index/{id}?var1=true
```

The user is then presented with the above links again. Of course, if the user clicks again on another action link, only the new parameter is there.

```
Page/Index/{id}?var2=true
```

What I want instead is to **make the action links retain all the previously passed parameters and add a new one** (or replace it if it already has a value in the request).

```
Page/Index/{id}?var1=true&var2=true
```

How can I do that?

It is crucial that I don't hardcode all the possible parameter names and I'd also find it very inelegant to do string manipulation to the URL directly. I should also note that the parameters are completely independent of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques for doing this, however, none of them is fully automatic, you still have to tell the ActionLink explicitly what you want inside the actionlink.

There are a few questions on stackoverflow that describe the same or a similar problem which you could check out:

- [MVC ActionLink add all (optional) parameters from current url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779932/mvc-actionlink-add-all-optional-paramters-from-current-url)
- [ASP.NET MVC ActionLink keep "old" route arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350562/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-keep-old-route-arguments)

Comment: The first link's answer is exactly what I needed. Thank you!